# java setvisible(false) from mainframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have **class Main (jFrame)** and **class Edit (jFrame)** I want to double click cell from table and show **Edit (jFrame)** so when i double click new cell i want to close old **Edit (jFrame)** before show new **Edit (jFrame)**.Thanks

```
jTable1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    JTable table =(JTable) me.getSource();
    Point p = me.getPoint();
    int row = table.rowAtPoint(p);
    if (me.getClickCount() == 2) {
        Edit n = new Edit();
        player.stop();

        n.setVisible(false);//It's not work.

        n.setVisible(true);
        Object ed = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 2);
        Edit.jTextArea1.setText((String) ed);
        Edit.x = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    }
}

    });
```

Comment: `n` isn't the current window, it's the new window

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Thanks everybody now i fix by build frame in mainclass